# JBoss EAP 6.4 clustering in HornetQ although they are in different box

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq

I have 2 different boxes in my configuration. And each box contains 2 instances of JBoss EAP 6.4 . I am using `stanadalone-full-ha.xml` configuration for all instances.

I start 2 instances in 2 different box in following way:

```
standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b ipOfOneMachineInFirstBox -u 230.0.0.4 -Djboss.node.name=node1

standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b ipOfOneMachineInSecondBox -u 230.0.0.5  -Djboss.node.name=node1
```

When each JBoss is started I can see messages in the log that they connected wit a cluster.

```
13:28:21,715 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (Thread-28 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=c08d2d4d-1444-11e9-8c21-839549bb27e4-1283024282)) HQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@7d2f5397 [name=sf.my-cluster.f79947a0-1444-11e9-b0dd-e959e93529ee, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.my-cluster.f79947a0-1444-11e9-b0dd-e959e93529ee, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=c08d2d4d-1444-11e9-8c21-839549bb27e4]]@557c5a54 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@7d2f5397 [name=sf.my-cluster.f79947a0-1444-11e9-b0dd-e959e93529ee, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.my-cluster.f79947a0-1444-11e9-b0dd-e959e93529ee, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=c08d2d4d-1444-11e9-8c21-839549bb27e4]]@557c5a54 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=netty, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=5445&host=**ipOfOnMachineInSecondBox**], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@837873239[nodeUUID=c08d2d4d-1444-11e9-8c21-839549bb27e4, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=netty, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=5445&host=**ipOfOneMachineInFirstBox**, address=jms, server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=c08d2d4d-1444-11e9-8c21-839549bb27e4])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration
```

I think I need to change something in `standalone-full-ha`. They both use same configuration. Is just changing name is ok?

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.4">
        <hornetq-server>
            <clustered>true</clustered>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
            <cluster-password>${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:CHANGE ME!!}</cluster-password>
            <backup>false</backup>
            <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </netty-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </connectors>

            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </netty-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </acceptors>

            <broadcast-groups>
                <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
                    <socket-binding>messaging-group</socket-binding>
                    <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
                    <connector-ref>
                        netty
                    </connector-ref>
                </broadcast-group>
            </broadcast-groups>

            <discovery-groups>
                <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
                    <socket-binding>messaging-group</socket-binding>
                    <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
                </discovery-group>
            </discovery-groups>

            <cluster-connections>
                <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                    <address>jms</address>
                    <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
                    <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
                </cluster-connection>
            </cluster-connections>

            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>

            <address-settings>
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                    <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes>
                    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>

            <jms-connection-factories>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                    <ha>true</ha>
                    <block-on-acknowledge>true</block-on-acknowledge>
                    <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
                    <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
                    <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
                </connection-factory>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <transaction mode="xa"/>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>

            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue">
                    <entry name="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ">
                    <entry name="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-queue name="SiGuardServerQueue">
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/queue/siguard/serverQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-topic name="SiGuardClientTopic">
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/topic/siguard/clientTopic"/>
                </jms-topic>
                <jms-topic name="SiGuardNodeTopic">
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/topic/siguard/nodeTopic"/>
                </jms-topic>
            </jms-destinations>
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default each HornetQ instance using `standalone-full-ha.xml` will use UDP multicast to broadcast information about itself and also listen for information about other potential cluster members out on the network. In general, nodes which use the same multicast IP address & port will find each other and form a cluster.

If you don't want nodes to cluster together at all then you shouldn't configure clustering.

If you want to have multiple independent clusters of nodes on the same network then each cluster must use unique multicast addresses by specifying the following on the command-line:

- `-u`: This controls the `jboss.default.multicast.address` system property in the server configuration which is used in the `socket-binding-group`. By default it is `230.0.0.4`.
- `-Djboss.messaging.group.address`: This controls the multicast address used by the `messaging-group` `socket-binding` used for HornetQ clustering. By default it is `231.7.7.7`.

In your case, I'd recommend starting your JBoss instances with something like this:

```
standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b ipOfOneMachineInFirstBox -u 230.0.0.4 -Djboss.messaging.group.address=231.7.7.7 -Djboss.node.name=cluster1-node1

standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b ipOfOneMachineInSecondBox -u 230.0.0.5  -Djboss.messaging.group.address=231.7.7.8 -Djboss.node.name=cluster2-node1
```

Comment: I edited my post. I use  230.0.0.4 as multicast address İn fisrt clustering. So I do not know what is going on

Comment: But I defined multicast address by specifying only -u option. I think I need to define 230.0.0.5 in configuration of second cluster. Do you know how to change it?